# Wordpress images link

Tags: wordpress

I'm just starting with wordpress. I create blog and right now I have index.php with list of posts. If I add images to posts in admin panel , images have href but they redirect to attachment - not to post. Of course I can use:

```
has_post_thumbnail()
```

but this works only if I set it in admin.

My question is : How to create redirect to post as default (not to attachment ) for images added to post.

Comment: The link for a inline image is configured through the post editor.

Comment: so you have less knowledge in wordpress than I ... there is no redirect to post in admin - but I want to set as default redirect to post.

Comment: ... which means you either need to 1. hook the URL for inline images and/or add a new option for the editor, or 2. use the post thumbnail (hint: go for #2).

Comment: very verry helpful, of course, it's irony ...

Answer (score 1):

This is typical of WordPress and is supposed to happen. It is up to the author when inserting media into the page how it is displayed. See the Attachment Settings in the Bottom Right of the Corner. You will want to select None or Custom URL based on your preferences. Yours is currently set to "Media File" Like the screenshot below.

You can add this snippet of code to your themes **functions.php** file to change the default settings:

```
function image_overrides() {
    update_option('image_default_align', 'center' ); // Changes the alignment 
    update_option('image_default_link_type', 'none' ); // Changes the Link type
    update_option('image_default_size', 'large' ); // Changes the default size

}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'images_overrides');
```

[image]